# Validar data no editfor

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Fiz uma máscara de data e gostaria de saber, como eu valido a data ali mesmo, ou seja, já no edit ele não aceite data tipo: **23/16/9087**. Esse é meu editfor de data

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "nascimento" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Na model eu exibo uma mensagem de obrigatoriedade da data(caso esteja vazio), mas se for uma data inválida ele passa assim mesmo e não quero jogar essa regra pro banco.

Como eu valido?

```
public class Funcionario
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Nome do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings =false)]
        [Display(Name ="Nome")]
        public String nome { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Nascimento do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        public String dataNascimento { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "CPF")]
        public String cpf { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Nome da Cidade")]
        public String NomeCidade { get; set; } 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cidade do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
        public virtual int cidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: poste a sua model

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, postei a model

Comment: Se é um campo de Data, porque você usou string no lugar de DateTime?

Comment: Se for manter assim vai ter que fazer a validação por Regex

Comment: Como assim, @LeandroAngelo. O que eu tenho que fazer?

Comment: Primeiro, A data de nascimento devia ser tipo Data desde o banco de dados e assim refletir em sua Entidade e ViewModel

Comment: É que ao passar a data, ela só aceita no formato yyyy-mm-dd e se eu der um convert no banco para exibir em nosso format, não consigo inserir. Alterei para DateTime

Comment: Não cara, você está fazendo isso errado, O banco vai guardar a data no formato dele, Como você vai exibir é outra parada com o Sistem.Globalization

Comment: Eu sei, já consertei isso também. Agora eu coloquei todos DateTime e a máscara funciona

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81489/discussion-between-leandro-angelo-and-pnet).

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o atributo **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute**.

Exemplo:

```
[Range(typeof(DataTime), "01/01/2001", "01/01/2020", ErrorMessage = "Data Inválida")]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```